# Xcart Getting error when apply upgrade pack

Tags: upgrade, x-cart

I am getting error Fatal error: Call to undefined function func_version_compare() in D:\Xampp5\htdocs\xcart\prepare.php on line 528

when apply upgrade pack from admin 4.1.8 to 4.1.12

Answer (score 1):

The best option for you might be this.

1. Make a DB backup
2. Download x-cart-4.1.8gold.tgz  or x-cart-4.1.8pro.tgz from the ticket https://bt.x-cart.com/view.php?id=50230#attachments
3. Install x-cart-4.1.8gold.tgz or x-cart-4.1.8pro.tgz according to your current X-Cart edition

   3.1. Retrieve the value of the variable $blowfish_key from the file /config.php of your existing X-Cart installation and temporarily save it somewhere on your local computer.
   You will be asked to provide the Blowfish key later on to allow X-Cart to decrypt the data in the existing database.

   3.2. Install a fresh copy of X-Cart 4.1.8 in a new (empty) folder using the existing database's credentials

   3.2. IMPORTANT: At the step 'Preparing to Install X-Cart Database' of the installation wizard, select the check box 'Update config.php only' and enter the Blowfish key for the upgraded database
4. Upgrade the just installed X-Cart 4.1.8 to X-Cart 4.1.12 in the usual way.

As result, you will upgrade your database to 4.1.12 version.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make a backup of the XCART_DIR/prepare.php file somewhere.
2. Download  prepare.php file  from the ticket 
   https://bt.x-cart.com/view.php?id=50230#attachments to a temp folder.
3. Unpack the upgrade 4.1.8-4.1.12 pack to X-Cart folder
4. Copy the file to XCART_DIR folder.
5. Apply the upgrade pack from the
   admin area.

P.S. 
Try the other solution below.